# Is the integral closure of a ring of integers in finite separable extension a ring of integers?

Tags: galois-extensions, integer-rings

Let $K/F$ be a finite separable extension of number fields of finite degree over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $A = \mathcal{O}_F$ and $B$ the integral closure of $A$ in $K$. Is $B = \mathcal{O}_K$?

> Let us recall that given the rings $R_1\subseteq R_2$, an element $\alpha\in R_2$ is integral over $R_1$ if $\alpha$ is a root of a monic polynomial $P\in R_1[X]$. With that definition, the integral closure of $R_1$ in $R_2$ is the set of elements in $R_2$ that are integral over $R_1$. IF $K$ is a field then we denote by $\mathcal{O}_K$ the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the field $K$.

Here's my attempt:

First of all, since $\mathbb{Z}\subseteq \mathcal{O}_F$ then any element $\beta\in K$ integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ is trivially integral over $A$, so $\mathcal{O}_K \subseteq B$. I suspect that the converse inclusion is also true.

If $\alpha$ in $B$ then it is a root of some monic polynomial

$$X^n + a_{n-1}X^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1X + a_0,$$

where each $a_i\in \mathcal{O}_F$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. $a_i$ is the root of a monic polynomial of degree $d_i$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X_i]$:

$$X_i^{d_i} + b_{i,d_i-1}X_i^{d_i-1} + \ldots + b_{i,1}X_i + b_{i,0}$$

where each $b_{i,j}\in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $0 \leq i < n$, $0\leq j < d_i$

We can construct a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X,X_{n-1},\ldots,X_1,X_0]$ that has $(\alpha,a_{n-1},a_{n-2},\ldots,a_1,a_0)$ as a zero:

$$X^n + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left( X^iX_i^{d_i} + \sum_{j=0}^{d_i-1} b_{i,j}X^iX_i^j\right).$$

I'm trying to find a clever way to unify all this variables into a single one without compromising the coefficients, but so far I've been unable to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to find a specific polynomial with coefficients in $A$ for $\alpha\in B$. Simply observe that, since $\mathbf Q\subset A \subset B$, $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module. On the other hand, $A$ is  a finitely generated $\mathbf Z$-module, so $B$ is also a finitely generated $\mathbf Z$-module, therefore it is integral over  $\mathbf Z$. This proves $B\subset \mathcal O_K$.

Conversely, any element of $O_K$, being integral over  $\mathbf Z$ is *a fortiori* integral over A, so $O_K\subset B$.

Comment: I know that $A[b]$ is a finitely generated $A$-module for all $b\in B$ integral over $A$ but why is $B$ a finitely generated $A$-module?

Comment: There's no need to prove that $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module. If $b\in B$ is integral over $A$ then $A[b]$ is a finitely generated $A$-module and by transitivity of finite generation it is also a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module, therefore $b$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It is a well-known result that the integral closure of a noetherian domain $A$ in a finite separable extension of its field of fractions is a finite $A$-module (one shows it is a submodule of a finite $A$-module, so it is noetherian).